# 16 bit float and 32 bit float doubts

Tags: painting, krita, depth

I'm starting in digital paint and I cant figure if it would be better to work in a 16 or 32 floating point bit rate depth, or even neither?

I've noticed that working in a floating point precision is important for HDR paint, but apart from it I'm still not sure if there exist any advantage. And most importantly, any advantage in sRGB color space work.

## conclusion:

This discussion was somewhat vague as I myself had near zero experience with digital painting.

Particularly by being "transparent" about how things are done Krita works in a way completely different from Photoshop (and it is good, you get to learn a lot! Maybe it will cut a lot of work needed to get familiar with weird color mixing and "[magic](https://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/test-for-linear-processing.html)").

Particularly I answered a question about painting here that can answer a lot of doubts:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107632/42515

Going to the point... **16 bits may matter** (and some editors may hide it from you), linear color spaces can be really great and they need 16 bit, also it produces much less banding due to math on smudging paint methods to mimic wet techniques. But clearly it mostly depends on the result you expect while painting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Notations of color depth

There are 2 ways to describe color depth. An older total bits per pixel, and a newer colors per channel.

The older model describes total memory usage per pixel. The only time this model is generally used is when talking of indexed color formats or monitor color mode. This should be considered legacy as its nomenclature clashes with the newer one. tough be honest only 8 bit and  32 bit color is confusable with he per pixel variant. the 32 bit color is the reason why this model has been deprecated, because 32 bit color can not actually be displayed as one of the color channels is alpha which isn't a color at all.

Now for composing of images its a bit misleading to talk of total numbers of bits per pixel (its ok for traditional image formats like jpeg and png tough). Since you have possibly many layers and many channels. So saying the total bit amount says little if you dont know how many channels your using. So instead its been decided to talk how many bits each channel eats. This causes a bit of confusion as the most common formats are (in increasing rarity):

- 8-bit integer  per channel  (often just known as 8-bit)
- 16-bit integer  per channel  (often just known as 16-bit)
- half float (or 16 bit float)
- float (or a 32 bit float)

### do you need higher bitness?

Depends on what you do. In general *if you need to ask you do not need this info* (see [What benefits are there to workflows using Images at 32-bits per channel?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/50943/18306) for a alternate answer).

For photography, 3d arts, animation, and science it can be useful. However the floating point format brings in its own convolutions. For painting the more than full color values bring minimal additional info. Your also going to limit your options quite much if you do.

So i would say its not useful for somebody designing for print or web today wont see much of benefit over a 16 bit integer image, even so its a bit overkill and 8 bits is enough to almost all work. With one exception you need to integrate photographic elements that may need some serious (and i do mean **serious**) color correction afterward.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm sure I didn't need in any way 32 float bit per channel... I'm just thinking in using 16 bloat bit per channel because I was reading nvidia works natively in floating point precision so maybe I can avoid conversion overhead and gain in terms of speed.

Comment: @user2884025 Float images slow you down. If the only reason is you heard something then you dont need it.

Comment: Could have also added in that there are 4 channels (3 channels and an alpha channel, hence why 8-bit is actually more commonly known as 32-bit depth (windows) and also as 24-bit depth (Linux; maybe also OS X, not sure about that one, counting the alpha channel is kinda silly but it's used to make the number higher, and make it sound cooler))

You also could have added that most computer monitors are not capable of displaying anything higher than said 24 bit depth (some 10-bit monitors are being released with 1 bln colors instead of 16.7m colors, that's just 10 bit. Not even 16.)

Comment: this is somewhat old and I have it pretty clear today, the point is not what you see just, I focus on sRGB, I don't need more than 24 bits (8 bpc) output there to correctly see things, but as it is about painting it is better to working in a canvas where color blending math is orthogonal/correct, you will need a linear color space for this and 8 bpc precision will not be enough.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti kindof, many monitors have actually 10 bpc color today. And theres no reason why you cluldnt make your moniotor linear, just that all other stuff would look wrong. You can also calculate each step linarily at higher biitness before committing, so no for painting generally 8bpc is enough after all what you see is what you ship.

Comment: No it isn't... It will produce a lot of banding, non linear sRGB is exactly because for this, 256 linearly distributed intensities produce really perceptible banding on darker values as we perceive it better. So no, the workspace can't be a non linear 8 bpc CS.

There is no need for a linear color space monitor neither a 10 bpc non linear, it is a need to avoid non real color mixes, transformations go wrong on non orthogonal spaces.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti yes but the underlying operation of the gradient can dither the result As it operates on each value computed linear and converting it immediately to sRGB. This is after all how 90% of all painting is done and it works quite well without banding.  Because theres a human in the loop if it does not work. However the higher is MUCH more important if you chain photo manipulation operations. Where the human is much furher away form the loop.  Also note that 256 levels of color is not enough to make banding free color. Fortunataly any nonpure color will not have this problem

Comment: @joojaa No, I don’t know what Photoshop do, but in Krita the working space can be for example 16 bits linear sRGB, all the math will be done with those values without conversion between intermediate results from brush smudge, Krita has support inside itself for n displays color spaces, canvas is converted with some intent only for the purpose of viewing in this CS, much like color proof without gamut warnings, obviously this is again mapped by the OS color management, if it is calibrated to sRGB you would not see any difference from using the display or a linear 2.2 gamut sRGB.

Comment: @joojaa in terms of banding there is not any relevant banding perceptible for artistic painting in non-linear 8bpc, sure, pure components gradient will be perceptible, but it’s so uncommon generally a natural dithering occurs through the process as there is not normal to exist pure shadows in real world. The problem is that mix is going wrong, most artists forced themselves to learn a weird color mixing where you more build gradient than mix colors, that is inconvenient, and at linear color space, well banding is unavoidable, is present even in a all components colors mixing with 8 bpc.

Comment: To anyone interested on the problem visually: https://imgur.com/lorynmM, you can see linear mix well... and posterize pretty quick on dark spectrum.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti Yes offcourse. But my point is you dont need to work in linear mode to get linear mixing (PS has options for doing this in settings). Its perfectly possible for the system to roundtrip via a linear workspace. Some applications actually do that so there is no need to do what you say. This is more of a circumbention of the stupidity of your painting app than a real need for 16 bit color. Though circumvention is a perfectly good reason as any.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti But if you add that as an answer to your own post i would upvote it

Comment: @joolaa I would be grateful If you can point me this setting, so I can test those solutions that produce correct additive mixing? Because I've seen a mix of not good tricks like using specific blend modes, when I just want to mix without going calibrating my tools. Honestly I'm on the discussion to get + info and if possible a better solution, if I can do real color mixture (without picking intermediate values to build a gradient) of dark colors without getting this kind of posterization in 8 bits I'm just interested.

Comment: In fact I believe this is a good point for a question. :)

Answer (score 0):

For expanded color and dynamic ranges, start with 32 bit color. This will produce the highest quality rendering - 4,294,967,296 possibly colors including alpha channels for 32 bit, compared to 65,536 with 16 bit.

Depending on where the final asset will end up, I recommend down sampling it to 16 bit to save file space. 32 bit files are huge in comparison and cannot even be exported in many common formats.

sRGB was created for digital screens, so if that is where it will end up, that is the best color space and most common period.

Also, googling these topics will yield and encyclopedia's amount of info. If you have a very targeted question, please comment below.

Hope that helps!

Comment: He si talking of 32 bit floating point which is per channel

Comment: @joojaa exactly...

Comment: Yes, but I find so many controversial info there... http://www.kenrockwell.com/ point its irrelevant to work with wider color spaces...
Some say I will obtain better refined brushes like airbrush the higher I goes in depth... Others only point its relevant for HDR paint intentions...
I came here looking for some concise information if possible...